# Powershell command to create a schedule task to execute a batch file during bootup

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

How to use Powershell command to create a Windows schedule task to execute a batch file during startup?

PLease provide an example commands, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Yourbatchhere.bat"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$principal = "Computername\youruseraccount"
$setting = New-ScheduledTaskSettingSet
$inputTask = -action $action -principal $principal -trigger $trigger -settings
Register-ScheduledTask BatchRunTask -InputObject $inputTask
```

I suggest that you try this, and fill in the fields with the appropriate information, as I pulled this almost directly off Technet. It should create a task running your batch file under your account at logon. Make sure to run it as admin to ensure it works, though.

The reference is [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649810.aspx) if you need it again later.